# JAX-WS: Assembling the enunciate app using CXF

Tags: web-services, cxf, enunciate, appfuse, qnames

I am customizing an [appfuse](http://appfuse.org) 3.0.0 Web Service Only artifact. I have faced this stacktrace when trying to add a checked exception to my Web Service:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-cxf-plugin:1.28:assemble (default) on project ibnInq: Problem assembling the enunciate app. local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-cxf-plugin:1.28:assemble (default) on project ibnInq: Problem assembling the enunciate app.

Problem assembling the  enunciate app.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:364)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:198)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Problem assembling the enunciate app.
at org.codehaus.enunciate.AssembleMojo.execute(AssembleMojo.java:75)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName
at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:244)
at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:188)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.contract.jaxws.WebFault.getParticleQName(WebFault.java:280)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.contract.jaxws.WebMethod.getReferencedNamespaces(WebMethod.java:232)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.contract.jaxws.EndpointInterface.getReferencedNamespaces(EndpointInterface.java:229)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.config.WsdlInfo.getImportedNamespaces(WsdlInfo.java:132)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.xml.WsdlInfoModel.get(WsdlInfoModel.java:50)
at freemarker.core.Dot._getAsTemplateModel(Dot.java:76)
at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:614)
at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:310)
at freemarker.core.CompressedBlock.accept(CompressedBlock.java:73)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:310)
at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:310)
at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:259)
at   org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.FreemarkerDeploymentModule.processTemplate(FreemarkerDeploymentModule.java:106)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.FreemarkerDeploymentModule.processTemplate(FreemarkerDeploymentModule.java:85)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.FreemarkerDeploymentModule.processTemplate(FreemarkerDeploymentModule.java:70)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.xml.XMLDeploymentModule.doFreemarkerGenerate(XMLDeploymentModule.java:340)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.FreemarkerDeploymentModule.doGenerate(FreemarkerDeploymentModule.java:51)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.modules.BasicDeploymentModule.step(BasicDeploymentModule.java:107)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.apt.EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.process(EnunciateAnnotationProcessor.java:128)
at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessors.java:84)
at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Apt.java:480)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.AptJavaCompiler.compile(AptJavaCompiler.java:270)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1127)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:989)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:113)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:103)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.invokeApt(Enunciate.java:817)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate.doGenerate(Enunciate.java:401)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.ConfigMojo$MavenSpecificEnunciate.doGenerate(ConfigMojo.java:670)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.step(Enunciate.java:1799)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.main.Enunciate$Stepper.stepTo(Enunciate.java:1831)
at org.codehaus.enunciate.AssembleMojo.execute(AssembleMojo.java:71)
... 25 more
```

My enunciate version is 1.28, and I have enabled cxf module in enunciate.xml:

```
<cxf disabled="false"/>
```

I have used [JAX-WS Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxws-2.2-mrel3-evalu-oth-JSpec/jaxws-2_2-mrel3-spec.pdf) for exception throwing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have done following workaround to fix my problem: adding @XmlRootElement to my FaultBean.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FaultBean",propOrder = {"errorDescription",errorCode"})
public class FaultBean implements Serializable {
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
protected String errorDescription;
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
protected String errorCode;

public FaultBean() {
}

public String getErrorDescription() {
    return this.errorDescription;
}

public void setErrorDescription(String var1) {
    this.errorDescription = var1;
}

public String getErrorCode() {
    return this.errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(String var1) {
    this.errorCode = var1;
}
}
```